# Need a way to grab information out of a file and skip if information is in another file

Tags: ruby

I have a file called `skip.txt` that contains the following information:

```
stackoverflow.com 
github.com 
www.sa-k.net 
yoursearch.me 
search1.speedbit.com 
duckfm.net
search.clearch.org 
webcache.googleusercontent.com
```

I also have a file called `information.txt` that contains this information:

```
http://search.clearch.org/?a=web&q=Viewcat_h.php%3Fidcategory%3D%20%3Cstrong%3ESite%3C%2Fstrong%3E%20.pl%20
https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=246409
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:oqPwN7FtDWgJ
http://www.aquariumist.com.ua/spr.php?id=7
http://search.clearch.org/?a%3Dweb%26q%3DViewcat_h.php%253Fidcategory%253D%2520%253Cstrong%253ESite%253C%252Fstrong%253E%2520.pl%2520%2Binurl:viewCat_h.php?idCategory%3D&hl=en&gbv=1&ct=clnk
http://www.astbury.leeds.ac.uk/research/spr.php
http://www.media4play.li/s/spr+php+id.html
http://v.virscan.org/SPR/PHP.ID.html
http://search.clearch.org/?a=images&q=Viewcat_h.php%3Fidcategory%3D+
http://search.clearch.org/?a=web&q=Inurl%20Viewcat_h.php%3Fidcategory%3D%20Site%20Clinsp=%3Fpvaid%3D97f2b2aa136c4af0936453a19d9ab1b2%26fcoid%3D302363
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:5qNE1JBqUeIJ
http://search.clearch.org/?a%3Dweb%26q%3DInurl%2520Viewcat_h.php%253Fidcategory%253D%2520Site%2520Cl%26insp%3D%253Fpvaid%253D97f2b2aa136c4af0936453a19d9ab1b2%2526fcoid%253D302363%2Binurl:viewCat_h.php?idCategory%3D&hl=en&gbv=1&ct=clnk
```

I want a way to grab this information and move to the `next` url, is there a way I could read from the `skip.txt` file and if the `information.txt` file contains anything on that `skip.txt` file move to the next url in the file?

Expected output:

```
http://www.astbury.leeds.ac.uk/research/spr.php
http://www.media4play.li/s/spr+php+id.html
http://v.virscan.org/SPR/PHP.ID.html
https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=246409
http://www.aquariumist.com.ua/spr.php?id=7
```

I've done a little research and found the `grep` function, but that would require a complex regex, at which I'm not very good.. So if you can either help me find a way to skip over the information in `skip.txt`, or help me with a regex that would be great! Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: In future, please boil your examples down to essentials. To make your point, "skip_txt" could have been three or four lines and "information.txt" could have had fewer and much shorter lines. The lines in `skip.txt` all end with a trailing space, which obviously is not expected. I couldn't understand why my code wasn't working until I tracked the bug to those spaces. Please edit to remove them.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm sorry for that, I'm new around here. I'll edit the code to get rid of the trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you read the skip file into the variable `skip` and the information file into the variable `info_file`. Then

```
skip_arr = skip.split("\n").map(&:strip)
  #=> ["stackoverflow.com", "github.com", "www.sa-k.net", "yoursearch.me",
  #    "search1.speedbit.com", "duckfm.net", "search.clearch.org",
  #    "webcache.googleusercontent.com"]
```

`.map(&:strip)` (which you can think of as `.map { |s| s.strip }`) uses [String#strip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-strip) to remove any spaces that surround the elements of the array produced by `skip.split("\n")`. This may not be necessary but is a precaution does no harm.

```
info_arr = info.split("\n")
  #=> ["http://search.clearch.org/?a=web&q=Viewcat_h...,
  #    "https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=246409",
  #    "http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:oqPwN7FtDWgJ",
  #    "http://www.aquariumist.com.ua/spr.php?id=7",
  #    "http://search.clearch.org/?a%3Dweb%26q%3DViewcat_h.php...,
  #    "http://www.astbury.leeds.ac.uk/research/spr.php",
  #    "http://www.media4play.li/s/spr+php+id.html",
  #    "http://v.virscan.org/SPR/PHP.ID.html",
  #    "http://search.clearch.org/?a=images&q=Viewcat_h.php%3Fidcategory%3D+",
  #    "http://search.clearch.org/?a=web&q=Inurl%20Viewcat_h.php...,
  #    "http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:5qNE1JBqUeIJ",
  #    "http://search.clearch.org/?a%3Dweb%26q%3DInurl%2520Viewcat_h.php...]
```

Next we define a regular expression.

```
r = / 
    (?<=\/\/)  # match two forward slashes in a positive lookbehind
    #{ Regexp.union(skip_arr) } # match any element of skip_arr
    (?=\/)     # match a forward slash in a positive lookahead
    /x         # free-spacing regex definition mode
#=> / 
    (?<=\/\/)  # match two forward slashes in a positive lookbehind
    (?-mix:stackoverflow\.com|github\.com|www\.sa\-k\.net|yoursearch\.me|
      search1\.speedbit\.com|duckfm\.net|search\.clearch\.org|
      webcache\.googleusercontent\.com) # match any element of skip_arr
    (?=\/)     # match a forward slash in a positive lookahead
    /x
```

Lastly, use the method [Array#reject](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-reject) to remove those elements of `info.arr` that match this "regex":

```
info_arr.reject { |s| s =~ r }
  #=> ["https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=246409",
  #    "http://www.aquariumist.com.ua/spr.php?id=7", 
  #    "http://www.astbury.leeds.ac.uk/research/spr.php",
  #    "http://www.media4play.li/s/spr+php+id.html",
  #    "http://v.virscan.org/SPR/PHP.ID.html"]
```